# Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model something like this:

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    progress = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    estimated_days = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now I would like to do a calculation `Sum(progress * estimated_days)` on the database level. Using Django Aggregation I can have the sum for each field but not the summation of multiplication of fields.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Update:** for **Django >= 1.8** please follow the answer provided by @kmmbvnr

it's possible using Django ORM:

here's what you should do:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total = ( Task.objects
            .filter(your-filter-here)
            .aggregate(
                total=Sum('progress', field="progress*estimated_days")
             )['total']
         )
```

Note: if the two fields are of different types, say `integer` & `float`, the type you want to return should be passed as the first parameter of `Sum`

It's a late answer, but I guess it'll help someone looking for the same.

Comment: Works well, thanks, but beware that the *field* kwarg is not documented and that I didn't find any test about it in the Django test suite.

Comment: what does the 'progress' field accomplish? I'm trying to figure out this code snippet, since it's exacly what I need

Comment: @Maor I think you mean the first parameter of `Sum`? Well, then as I mentioned `if the two fields are of different types, say integer & float, the type you want to return should be passed as the first parameter of Sum`

Comment: @sha256, So I guess you mean the first parameter of Sum should be the name of the field in whose type you want the result to be returned? In this case the result will be returned in the field progress' datatype?

Comment: @BinojDavid, exactly!

Answer (score 104):

With Django 1.8 and above you can now pass an expression to your aggregate:

```
 from django.db.models import F

 Task.objects.aggregate(total=Sum(F('progress') * F('estimated_days')))['total']
```

Constants are also available, and everything is combinable:

```
 from django.db.models import Value

 Task.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('progress') / Value(10))['total']
```

Comment: I think this answer is easier to understand and maintain. Beside if the types of these field are different, add `output_field` parameter to aggregate function

Comment: I am trying it on django 1.7 but I am getting AttributeError `AttributeError: 'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'split'`, for what version my django version is 1.7.10

Comment: if `progress` is a ForienKey of some other model, for instance let it be `Product` and it has a field `price`, how should be reformate it? `Task.objects.aggregate(total=Sum(F('progress.price') * F('estimated_days')))['total']` doesn't work

Comment: This solution works for me in my scenario... Thanks

Answer (score 37):

The solution depends on Django version.

- **django < 1.8**

  ```
  from django.db.models import Sum
  MyModel.objects.filter(<filters>).aggregate(Sum('field1', field="field1*field2"))
  ```
- **django >= 1.8**

  ```
  from django.db.models import Sum, F
  MyModel.objects.filter(<filters>).aggregate(Sum(F('field1')*F('field2')))
  ```

Comment: When aggregation is made with different type fields, you need to use ExpressionWrapper.
Please, take a look to this solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458958/how-to-aggregate-the-average-of-a-calculation-based-on-two-columns?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

**Edited (after Django 1.8)**

Since Django 1.8, you can use `F`:

```py
from django.db.models import F. Sum

total = ( 
    Task
    .objects
    .aggregate(total=Sum(F('progress') * F('estimated_days'))) 
    ['total']
)
```

**Old answer (before Django 1.8)**

*This answer was wrote on 2012 and django 1.8 was published on 2015*

Do you have several options:

1. [Raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)
2. [Emulbreh's undocumented approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195517/842935)
3. Create a third field `progress_X_estimated_days` and update it in save overwrited method. Then do aggregation through this new field.

Overwriting:

```
class Task(models.Model):
   progress = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   estimated_days = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   progress_X_estimated_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      progress_X_estimated_days = self.progress * self.estimated_days
      super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was actually keeping the Raw SQL or an additional attribute as the last option. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can use the @property decorator before defining a method for performing calculations, like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    progress = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    estimated_days = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
    @property
    def new_number(self):
        new_number = self.progress * self.estimated_days
        return new_number
```

Then, you can access it normally, calling {{task.new_number}} on the template, for example.