# How to calculate the total of two fields for each item in the queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

Assume I have the following model Structure:

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    base_price = DecimalField(....)
    commision = DecimalField(....)
```

I do not want to store `total_price` in my database for data consistency and wish to calculate it as `base_price + commision` like

```
SomeModel.Objects.all().xxxxxx(total_price=base_price + commision)
```

So my database (Postgresql 9.1) will calculate and return it without recording it on the database and each record in returning queryset will contain `total_price` that is sum of `base_price` and `commision` of that record. also it would be great if I can use `filter` on calculated field.

How can I do that?

I want something that is similar to following SQL:

```
select ("base_price" + "commision") as total_price, base_price, commision from some_table;

total_price | base_price | commision
-------------------------------------
    15.0    |   14.0     |    1.0
    22.0    |   20.0     |    2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You can use the [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) QuerySet method:

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={'total_price': 'base_price + commission'})
```

The above will add a `total_price` attribute to each item in the QuerySet. However, you will **NOT** be able to filter on it--you'll get a `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'total_price' into field`.

**2.** There is an [undocumented way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19888120/3096768) to use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) to add a field that can be filtered on. In your case it'd be something like:

```
from django.db.models import Max

# with this method the total_price can be filtered on
SomeModel.objects.annotate(
    total_price=Max('base_price', field='base_price + commission')
).filter(total_price__lt=20)
```