# Use method as aggregate field

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have two models that go as follows (for simplicity's sake):

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Person(models.Model):
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank)
    savings = models.IntegerField()
    debts = models.IntegerField()

    def get_net_worth(self):
        return self.savings - self.debts
```

And I want to write a method that lets me know the "total net worth" of the people in a bank, like:

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_net_worth(self):
        return self.person_set.all().aggregate(Sum('get_net_worth'))
```

But of course Django complains that such field does not exist:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'get_net_worth' into field.

Is there a way to achieve this without having to explicitly store the "net worth" in the database?

**Edit:**

In case you wonder, one can just do

```
def get_net_worth(self):
    person_queryset = self.person_set.all()
    return person_queryset.aggregate(Sum('savings'))['savings__sum'] - person_queryset.aggregate(Sum('debts'))['debts__sum']
```

But I do have to somehow **use the `get_net_worth` method** on every "Person".

**Edit 2:**

Just to clarify things up: These two are not my actual models, they are over-simplified examples of what I want to achieve, and what I essentially want to do **is NOT to do arithmetic between two fields**, but rather **use a model's method as the field for the aggregate function** (of course a method can do some more complex stuff before returning a value), therefore this one is not a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Off-topic but I'm curious, is there a reason savings and debts use integers?

Comment: I wrote the classes just to exemplify the issue, they're not the real models.

Comment: BTW, this would be possible in SQLAlchemy, blame Django for not making their ORM layer pluggable.

Comment: Probably be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289003/how-to-calculate-the-total-of-two-fields-for-each-item-in-the-queryset

Comment: Did you get an answer on that? I'm facing the exact same problem.