# Closest equivalent to SUM in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following SQL query:

```
select SUM(royalty_price*conversion_to_usd)from sales_raw where date='2012-06-01'
```

The closest I was able to come up with in django is:

```
sum(SalesRaw.objects.extra(
        select={'result': 'royalty_price * conversion_to_usd'}
    ).values_list('result', flat=True))
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Manager
result = Manager.raw(u"""select SUM(royalty_price*conversion_to_usd)from sales_raw where date='2012-06-01'""")
```

Bearing in mind that [django](http://djangoproject.com) doesn't discourage you from [using SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw), why not do so?

Answer (score 1):

From answer by [sha256](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1232826/sha256) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields), you can do something like this (not tested):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

result = SalesRaw.objects.filter(date='2012-06-01') \
    .aggregate(result=Sum('royalty_price', field='royalty_price*conversion_to_usd'))['result']
```