# Insert into a table after inserting data using the admin Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am new to Django...

I am inserting data into a table, lets call it the Bet table using the django admin. (Ie: Bets I made, where the fields are the game date, the result, how much I betted, if I won or lost the bet, etc...). 
However, I also want to know, at the end of each month, how much games I won, lost, how much I profited, etc. So I created the table MonthlyBets. What I want to do, is something similar to a DB trigger: Whenever I add a bet to the Bet table, using the django-admin, I want to add to the MonthlyBets table the profit I made, if I won or not, etc.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Seems to me that creating another table to hold the same data that is in the first table is redundant and unnecessary. Why not just create a view of the data in the first table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way would be not to create MonthlyBets at all. You can get monthly records by calculation from your Bet model like in **Section 2**(renamed Bet to Tip).
**Section 1**
If you insist on creating MonthlyBets model, you can overwrite [Django Admin save method](http://www.djangocurrent.com/2011/04/django-admin-override-save-for-model.html). Or listen for [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) of Bet model. If new Bet object is created, update MonthlyBets.

**Section 2** 
It is not very straightforward code, but it does calculate `Yield`, `Count` and `Win Ratio` for each month for Tip model.

```
for date in Tip.objects.datetimes('date_game', 'month', order='DESC'):
        date_filter['date_game__month'] = date.month
        date_filter['date_game__year'] = date.year
        date_yield, date_count, date_win = get_yield(date_filter)
        month_list.append({"month": date, "yield": date_yield,
                           "count": date_count,
                           "win": date_win})
```

And something like this in `utils.py` or wherever you keep your logic.

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
from django.db import models as db_models
def get_yield(filter={}):
    """
    @kwargs filter options = date_game__month=month, date_game__year=year, sport__name=sport, etc
    :return: yield, all_tips_count, win_tips_count
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields
    """
    win_sum = Tip.objects.filter(result=Tip.WIN, **filter).aggregate(total=Sum(F('odds')*F('stake'),
                                                                               output_field=db_models.DecimalField()))['total']
    if win_sum==None:
        win_sum=0
    stake_sum = Tip.objects.filter(result__in=[Tip.WIN, Tip.LOST], **filter).aggregate(total=Sum('stake'))['total']
    if stake_sum==None:
        return 0, Tip.objects.filter(result__in=[Tip.WIN, Tip.LOST], **filter).count(),\
               Tip.objects.filter(result__in=[Tip.WIN], **filter).count()
    return (win_sum-stake_sum)/stake_sum * 100,\
            Tip.objects.filter(result__in=[Tip.WIN, Tip.LOST], **filter).count(),\
            Tip.objects.filter(result__in=[Tip.WIN], **filter).count()
```