# How to set django model field as method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my model for user order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    """Order Models"""

    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name=_('Name'))

    total_order_cost = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=21,
        verbose_name=_('Total Order Cost'))
```

And my model for ordered items

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    """ Ordered Item Model """

    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,
        verbose_name=_('Order'))

    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('Price'))

    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Quantity'))

    total_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name=_('Total Price'))

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.get_cost()
        super(OrderItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Field total_price gets value from get_cost. How can I make field total_order_cost work the same way? I want it to get value from

```
def get_total_cost(self):
    return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())
```

I can't overwrite method save for total_order_cost, because when I save order object  - ordered items don't exist yet.
My view:

```
def make_order(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save() # here I save order object

            for item in cart:   # and here I save ordered items
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    product=item.product,
                    price=item.product.price,
                    quantity=item.quantity)

            cart.clear()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?status_message=%s'
                % (reverse('get_cart'), _('Thank you for your order!')))

    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'products/make_order.html', {
        'form': form})
```

UPDATE:
I understood that I need to use

```
@property
def total_order_cost(self):
    return self.orderitem_set.aggregate(total=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity')))['total']
```

But I don't now how to use it. I tried it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
class Order(models.Model): 
    total_order_cost = models.DecimalField( db_column='total_order_cost', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Total Order Cost')) 
    @property 
    def total_order_cost(self): 
        return self.orderitem_set.aggregate(total=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity')))['total']
```

Comment: I think you're conflating cost and price, and it will probably end up confusing someone at some point...

Comment: There's no trivial way to "set a model field as a method" without doing some serious metaclass hacking into the django ORM. Fields should be instances of `django.db.models.fields.Field`. A much simpler solution is to use a property, as suggested by @Tom.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are running into performance problems, why store derived data at all? You could drop the `total_price` field from `OrderItem` and the `total_order_cost` from `Order` and simply query for it when needed using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) and [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). How about [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30979665/7376):

```
@property
def total_order_cost(self):
    return self.orderitem_set.aggregate(total=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity')))['total']
```

Comment: Does `Sum(F('price'))` work with all db backends? I'm not sure how DecimalFields are stored in SQLite, but I believe that it only supports floats and integers natively.

Comment: @HåkenLid that's a good question and I don't know the answer-- I was actually going to include my typical pedantic advice about not storing money values in a float/ decimal field at all but that felt like confusing the issue.