# django: replace values() with filter() or only() but sum in same row

Tags: django

I got a query currently looking like this:

```
x = Model.objects.values("city").annotate(Sum("a")).annotate(Sum("b"))
```

`city` is a choicefield, which means I need to do `get_FOO_display()` on it, but I can't as `values()` returns a non-query set of a list of tuples, so everything’s evaluated there already.

If I change `values()` to `filter()` or `only()` it works, but assuming I got 2 db inputs, one adding 500 to `a` and one adding 500 to `b`, then it would create two rows in my table in the template, instead of summing both fields in same row.

How could I get the `value` from my choicefield and sum both values in the same row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165636/django-aggregation-summation-of-multiplication-of-two-fields)

Comment: No, I try to have three cols in a row, city, sum a and sum b. Not to multiply them.